# work in/at/on something

Tags: prepositions

So I want to write the following sentence about a future job that I would like to have but I don't know which preposition should I use.

> I would like to work **in/on/at** something related to arts.

Answer (score 6):

An example usage of each:

> I would like to work **in** oils.
>
> I would like to work **on** my restoration skills.
>
> I would like to work **at** Sotheby's.

**Edit:** following a comment

**In**

> I would like to work **in** blue.
>
> I would like to work **in** a gallery.
>
> I would like to work **in** the company of artists.

**On**

> I would like to work **on** restoration.
>
> I would like to work **on** a catalogue.

**At**

> I would like to work **at** The Tate Modern.

Comment: +1 for examples covering all of them, but the question seems to favor (1) or (2), with (1) being most likely to my eye. If you have an opinion on which the OP should use, they might benefit from its inclusion in your answer.

Comment: @Upper_Case thank you I have added more examples favouring (1) and (2) but I can't see how you deduced that.

Comment: If the OP is applying for a job and is using the construction in the question, my immediate reading would be along the lines of "I would like to work *in a field related to the arts*" (working in that field), or possibly "I would like to work *on something related to the arts*", (work on a particular art piece, or something describing the specific art or arts itself). The example sentence could be clearer, as with the definite article I included in my guesses, but for the intended purpose I just think those are most likely.

Comment: @Upper_Case oh I see – I had read the question as  "*something related to arts*, please fill in the options" because that is such a vague idea for a job application.

Comment: You've given lots of examples, but haven't provided much guidance to the learner as to what the different nuances are, or how to decide which one is more appropriate in different situations.